# Javascript working only in chrome but none other browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to populate the images in the background by javascript on page load. I tried with the following code snippet - I tried running it in Chrome locally as well as on localhost where it runs fine but in Firefox, Safari and all other browsers the images don't show up.

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.floor(Math.min(body.scrollHeight));
for(i=0; i<height; i++){
  var images = [],
  index = 0;
  images[0] = "<img id='rel' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MDU3NDQ5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU5MDUxNTE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[1] = "<img id='rel1' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk2NTI1MTU4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODg0OTY0Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[2] = "<img id='rel2' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[3] = "<img id='rel' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[4] = "<img id='rel1' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[5] = "<img id='rel2' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk4ODQzNDY3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODA0NTM4Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[6] = "<img id='rel' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjU4NDExNDM1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDIyMTgxNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[7] = "<img id='rel1' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[8] = "<img id='rel2' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc2MTQ3MDA1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODA3OTI4NjE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[9] = "<img id='rel' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTAzZmJiOGQtOWM3NS00MDEwLWJiNGEtN2QzMDM3NDJjMWQwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUzOTQ5MjY@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[10] = "<img id='rel1' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUyMTE0ODcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODE4NDQzNTE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[11] = "<img id='rel2' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjM2Nzg4MzkwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzA0OTE3NjE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[12] = "<img id='rel' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[13] = "<img id='rel1' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  images[14] = "<img id='rel2' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxMjgxNTk0MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIyOTg2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

  index = Math.round(Math.random() * images.length);

  document.write(images[index]);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="continer">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="images.js"></script>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @adeneo ...Apparently, when I don't see it's there. Even if I copy and paste it... It's still wrong, though - it can return a index that is greater than the max index.

Comment: @vlaz - yes it can, the correct method would indeed be `Math.floor`

Comment: And of course, ***never*** use `document.write`

Comment: yes I saw that math.floor Its working now

Comment: @viaz Thankq It is solved now. Math.floor workedd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox and some other browsers, the scrollbar isn't attached to the body, but the `documentElement` i.e. the `<html>` tag.

You have to check which one actually has the `scrollHeight`

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var bodyHeight = Math.floor(Math.min(body.scrollHeight));
var htmlHeight = Math.floor(Math.min(html.scrollHeight));

var height = Math.max(bodyHeight, htmlHeight);

for(i=0; i<height; i++){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is referring to the body and visual elements of the page, you need to execute your script after the page is loaded. I modified your code as blow and it now works in Chrome, IE, and FF.

The most critical change was to run the script from the onLoad() event.

```
<body  onload="showImages();">
```

Note I cut out a lot of the image array inserts here for brevity.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
function showImages() {
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.floor(Math.min(body.scrollHeight));
for(i=0; i<height; i++){
var images = [],
index = 0;
images[0] = "<img id='rel' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MDU3NDQ5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU5MDUxNTE@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

images[1] = "<img id='rel1' src='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk2NTI1MTU4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODg0OTY0Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg'>";

//  ...

index = Math.round(Math.random() * images.length);

document.write(images[index]);

}
}
</script>
 <body  onload="showImages();">
<div id="continer">``

</div>
```